# Jquery - Triggering click on mouseenter on div and unclick if clicked on any other button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-deployment

I want to trigger a click on "bigbutton" when hovering over a div, "div1". And if I click on any other button, the "bigbutton" needs to be unclicked and the click need to move the newly clicked button. Here's what I've tried:

Html

```
<div class="div1">
<button id="bigbutton">bigbutton</button>
<button type="button" id="button1">button1</button>
<buttton type="button" id="button2">button2</button>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bigbutton").click(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    });
    $(".div1").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#bigbutton").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

With the above code, I'm only able to do half of what I want. So, tried the following, did not work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bigbutton").click(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    });
    $(".div1").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#bigbutton").on('click');
    });
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#bigbutton").off('click');
    });
});
```

PS. I'm extremely sorry about the formating errors as my phone has a broken screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bigbutton").click(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    });
    $(".div1").mouseover(function () {
       $("#bigbutton").trigger('click');
    });
    $("#button1").click(function () {
      $("#bigbutton").off('mouseover').css("background-color", "");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="div1">
        <button id="bigbutton">bigbutton</button>
        <button type="button" id="button1">button1</button>
        <buttton type="button" id="button2">button2</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Even though I used a different method to do what I wanted, your code worked very well.

Comment: Glad i could help :)